# Django not sending an error from bad POST requests to a web redirect

Tags: django, httprequest

So, I have a setup where I have a site running django. I have a a webredirect in a frame of:

```
subdom.domain.com -> domain.com/sub
```

That I did this to mask the URL. Anyway, the problem seems to arise when sending a post request to *subdom.domain.com*.

Checking the Chrome Dev Panel I see the POST parameters in the header (under Form Data) and I see that it received an OK (200) response from the server but the server never actually gets that request. I know this because I checked and that view didn't ever receive a request of the method POST. Anyway know what the problem could be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a Django issue. User Agents are not supposed to automatically redirect POST requests. According to both [HTTP 1.0](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Code301) and [HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2) specification:

> If the [301 or 302] status code is received in response to a request
>   other than GET or HEAD, the user agent MUST NOT automatically redirect
>   the request unless it can be confirmed by the user, since this might
>   change the conditions under which the request was issued.

Most browsers makes a GET request to the new location, even if the original request was a POST.

You just need to make `domain.com/sub` an `action` of your forms, not `subdom.domain.com`.